# HTML5 - How to refresh a window everytime it gets resized?

Tags: html

I want to redraw elements each time the window size changes (rescaling it to fit the window).
I have already managed to make a code that fits to the window according to the dimensions, but when i resize the window i need to refresh it to get the rescale...

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

window.onresize

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
window.addEventListener('resize',label,false);
function label(){
    document.body.innerHTML=window.innerWidth;  
}
</script>
</html>
```